# trying to read data from serial port on button click event in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I have a problem on reading data from serial-port in my winform application...here is my code ..

```
private void rtrvBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnid = 2;
        mySerialPort = new SerialPort(port);
        mySerialPort.Open();
        compacket(btnid);

        if (combuffer[0] != 0)
        {
            mySerialPort.Write(combuffer, 0, 4);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.port_rec);
        }
        else
        {
            lblmsg.Text = "FL";
        }
        mySerialPort.Close();


        rtrvBtn.Enabled = false;
        conBtn.Enabled = true;
    }

public void port_rec(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = Convert.ToString(mySerialPort.ReadExisting());
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
```

so here i am not getting any data and i am not also entering the port_rec event also.. can any one help ... and my serial-port settings are like this ....

```
 public void SettingRS232(string port)
    {
        try
        {
            mySerialPort = new SerialPort(port);
            mySerialPort.PortName = port;
            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that these two methods are in the same class with a mySerialPort field. You shouldn't be making a new serial port object in the click event, you should be using the one you already have.

Comment: yeah i tried that before but it was not working.. the data wasn't going so i tried this now the data is going i checked that but i can't read now